# Sticky Element inside a Flex Container

Tags: html, css, angular, tailwind-css, sticky

I have two elements inside a flex container. When I scroll the page, the right element (second-element) should be sticky, but it doesn't work.

This is the structure of my code (I use Tailwind CSS and Angular):

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="first-element flex-grow">Some content</div>
  <app-links class="second-element"></app-links>
</div>
```

"app-links" is a angular component I defined, and this is it's structure:

```
<ul class="space-y-1 w-56 right-0 sticky">
<li><\li>
</ul>
```

The browser tells me that second-element is of the height of the flex container, but it should be the height of its own content. I tried applying h-auto to the component as well as to second-element, but it does not make a difference.